# adding xpath-default-namespace attribute to the final compiled/transformed schematron xslt file

Tags: xslt, xpath, schematron

I have to generate schematron files for various xml schema files using the available information under the appinfo elements (i do xsl transformation to generate schemantron files, which are compiled again later).

The xpath rules required for schematron assertions are written under this appinfo element. However, these xpath rules do not contain any namespace prefix. Thus i can't use the schematron *'ns'* tag to add a namespace to the compiled final xslt file.

The solution would be adding the ***xpath-default-namespace*** attribute to the final compiled xslt. Unfortunately i couldn't find any tag for adding xpath-default-namespace attribute.

Is there any workaround for this case? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not appear to be an option currently available to set a `xpath-default-namespace`. In addition to transforming the generated XSLT, another option would be to modify/extend the schematron XSLT to generate the desired output so that you can get it generated in a single pass.

1. Create a stylesheet that imports the `iso_schematron_skeleton_for_saxon.xsl`

Override the template that generates the `element to insert the`xpath-default-namespace` attribute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet  
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:axsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/TransformAlias" 
    xmlns:iso="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" 
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" 
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
    version="2.0"
    >
    <xsl:import href="iso_schematron_skeleton_for_saxon.xsl"/>
    <!-- Using XSLT 2 -->
    <xsl:template 
        match="iso:schema[@queryBinding='xslt2' or @queryBinding ='xpath2']" 
        priority="10">
        <axsl:stylesheet
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/">
            <!-- insert the default namespace attribute -->
            <xsl:attribute name="xpath-default-namespace" select="'http://your/default/namespace/goes/here'"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                select="iso:ns" />
            <!-- Handle the namespaces before the version attribute: reported to help SAXON -->
            <xsl:attribute name="version">2.0</xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="stylesheetbody"/>
            <!-- was xsl:call-template name="stylesheetbody"/ -->
        </axsl:stylesheet>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

2. Modify the `iso_svrl_for_xslt2.xsl` to import your overriding stylesheet:

Change the path to import your overriding XSLT:

```
<!-- Select the import statement and adjust the path as 
   necessary for your system.
-->
<xsl:import href="iso_schematron_skeleton_for_saxon_with_default_namespace.xsl"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since XSLT is an XML file, you could transform the compiled/transformed schematron XSLT and insert `@xpath-default-namespace` yourself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="xpath-default-namespace" select="'http://your/default/namespace'"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This helps sure. As schematron assertions are actually xpath expressions, i thought there must be a schematron way of doing this (as in case of ns).  a workaround is just a workaround :). thanks.

Comment: It is not currently supported in the Schematron stylesheets, but it wouldn't be too difficult to enhance them to achieve what you want, and avoid having to transform the content in another pass. I've added another answer with an explanation of one way to do it.